# Does the LCM of $ax$ and $bx$ equal $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\cdot x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, least-common-multiple

Let $a,b,x \in Z^+$. Prove that $\operatorname{lcm}(ax,bx) = \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\cdot x$.

Here are my thoughts:

Let $d = \operatorname{lcm}(ax, bx)$. By definition $ax|d$ and $bx|d$. Now it can be seen that $a|d$ and $b|d$. So, let e = lcm(a,b). e is merely the lcm(ax, bx) (which equals d) multiplied by x. So, ex = d, which means that x $\cdot$ lcm(a,b) = d."

I am not certain of my proof's validity and I feel it is too informal to be considered valid. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Do you mean lcm (least common multiple), or gcd (greatest common divisor)? If you mean lcm, then I think you wanted to write $ax\mid d$ ($ax$ divides $d$), not the reverse. Please edit your question to make sure it reflects what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice fact that you can use is that for any $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$, $$\text{lcm}(a,b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}.$$ So then you have that $$\text{lcm}(ax,bx)=\frac{x^2ab}{\gcd(ax,bx)}= \frac{x^2ab}{x \cdot \gcd(a,b)} = x \cdot \left( \frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)} \right) = x \cdot \text{lcm}(a,b).$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof, as written now, is incorrect:

> Now it can be seen that $d|a$ and $d|b$.

This is false, since if $a=6$, $b=4$, then $d=12$, and it is not true that $d|a$.